# Log OIDC evaluation in Quarkus

Tags: logging, openid-connect, quarkus

I am new to Quarkus and I am trying OIDC in Quarkus 1.13.3
I added the oidc-dependency and annotated my REST-Service-methods with @RolesAllowed.
When I call the service with an expired JWT-Token, I get 401, when I call with the wrong user group, I get 403, this is fine so far.
However, Quarkus does not write anything into the log when doing this. I need Log-messages stating that someone called with an invalid token or with a wrong user group.
How can I achieve this ? Even with quarkus.log.level=TRACE, I do not see any messages concerning the oidc evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, since I landed here while searching for the same. I added the following properties:

```
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.oidc".level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.oidc".min-level=TRACE
```

that way you can start seeing messages like this in the log

```
2023-09-11 11:39:02,664 DEBUG [io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcIdentityProvider] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-9) {} Starting creating SecurityIdentity
2023-09-11 11:39:02,665 DEBUG [io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcIdentityProvider] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-9) {} Verifying the JWT token with the local JWK keys
```